# Undirected unweighted sub-graph enumeration with threshold on node value

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

I have an undirected, unweighted graph $G=(V,E)$, and a function $f:V\to [0,1]$ where $[0,1]$ denotes the interval of real numbers from $0$ to $1$ inclusive.

Given an input threshold $t\in [0,1]$, I need an algorithm which returns all maximum sized connected sub-graphs $H\subseteq G$, such that every node $u\in H$ has $f(u)>t$.

Can you please provide an algorithm suggestion or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think there is something I didn't get, because what prevents you from deleting all nodes with value under the threshold, then searching for the largest connected component?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72307329/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151710/755.  lease [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).